# What's the verb form of whistle-blower?

Tags: word-request

How can I express the actions that a whistle blower does? I suspect it's *whistle blow* at first. But after some investigating, it seems wrong. I want to use it in a sentence like *Several people {whistle blowed?} the dirty secrets behind him*.

Comment: **Blow the whistle on....someone or something.**    https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blow--the--whistle--on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> Several people blew the whistle on him.

or

> Several people blew the whistle on his dirty secrets.

"Secrets behind him" sounds odd.